# working on redirect page on submit using script editor sp2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, javascript

i am working on submitting a form and passing lastname and firstname and redirect search to http://data. but when i click enter or click submit button it does not redirect to http://data and it just reload the correct page

The current code is place under script editor webpart

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquerysharepointform.googlecode.com/files/jquery.SharePointFormSubmit.js">


<script>
function($){
         $.fn.SharePointFormSubmit = function(element,method,action) {
            var e; // new input element
            var f = document.createElement("form"); // form
                f.method = method;
                 f.action = action;            
                f.setAttribute("style","display:none");

                $(element).find("input, select, textarea").each(function(){
                    e = document.createElement("input")
                    e.setAttribute("type", $(this).attr("type"));
                    e.setAttribute("id", $(this).attr("id"));
                   e.setAttribute("name", $(this).attr("name"));
                    e.setAttribute("value", $(this).val());
                  e.setAttribute("checked", $(this).attr("checked"));
                  e.setAttribute("multiple", $(this).attr("multiple"));
                    f.appendChild(e);
                });

                var s = document.body.appendChild(f);
                s.submit();
        };
    })(jQuery);
</script>

<div id="divIdForm">
  <h2>People &amp; Places Search</h2>

  <input type="text" name="firstName id="firstName" value="" size="21" maxlength="50" />
  <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" value="" size="22" maxlength="50" />


    <input type="submit" value="" class="search" onclick="jQuery().SharePointFormSubmit('#divIdForm', 'post','http://data/default.aspx')">


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Each Sharepoint page is embedded into a `<form>` already, so I see two options here:

1. You could try to change the `action` of the form `#aspnetForm`: `$('#aspnetForm').attr("action","http://data/default.aspx")` — and adapt your code to not create your own `<form>` but just add the fields you want into the page... I think it's the cleanest way to do it
2. Or you can define `WebForm_OnSubmit=function() { return false }` to block the original `<form>` and then just use your code as it is

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

**1. Create a HTML file which contain the following file**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquerysharepointform.googlecode.com/files/jquery.SharePointFormSubmit.js">


<script>
function($){
         $.fn.SharePointFormSubmit = function(element,method,action) {
            var e; // new input element
            var f = document.createElement("form"); // form
                f.method = method;
                 f.action = action;            
                f.setAttribute("style","display:none");

                $(element).find("input, select, textarea").each(function(){
                    e = document.createElement("input")
                    e.setAttribute("type", $(this).attr("type"));
                    e.setAttribute("id", $(this).attr("id"));
                   e.setAttribute("name", $(this).attr("name"));
                    e.setAttribute("value", $(this).val());
                  e.setAttribute("checked", $(this).attr("checked"));
                  e.setAttribute("multiple", $(this).attr("multiple"));
                    f.appendChild(e);
                });

                var s = document.body.appendChild(f);
                s.submit();
        };
    })(jQuery);
</script>

<div id="divIdForm">
  <h2>People &amp; Places Search</h2>

  <input type="text" name="firstName id="firstName" value="" size="21" maxlength="50" />
  <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" value="" size="22" maxlength="50" />


    <input type="submit" value="" class="search" onclick="jQuery().SharePointFormSubmit('#divIdForm', 'post','http://data/default.aspx')">


</div>
```

**2. Add PageViewer Webpart on the page and link to HTML file created above**

**3. In order to make HTML render content in SharePoint, i need to run the following script**

```
function Add-SPAllowedInlineDownloadedMimeType{
    [CmdLetBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeLine=$true)]
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPWebApplicationPipeBind]$WebApplication,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
        [string]$MimeType
    )
    process{
        $actualWebApp = $WebApplication.Read()
        if ($actualWebApp.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes -notcontains $mimetype)
        {
           Write-Host "Adding MIME Type..."
           $actualWebApp.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes.Add($mimetype)
           $actualWebApp.Update()
           Write-Host "Done."
        } Else {
           Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "MIME type is already added."
        }
    }
}

$url = http://contoso.com
Add-SPAllowedInlineDownloadedMimeType -WebApplication $url -MimeType "text/html"
```